# How do I allocate children to rooms based on the following constraints

Tags: constraints, matching, constraint-programming, minizinc

I need help with the constraint specification for a room allocation solution that I'm writing. So, the constraints are that only children of the same gender are allowed in the same room,children with disabilities can only be placed in rooms that are accesible to them and children in a room should all be around the same age, if possible (this is a soft constraint).  The ouput should be a list of the children who will be in each room.
I'll place the mzn code that I have so far below. I'd appreciate any help with this.

So, I wrote the model by defining what a child is and what a room is,and thus I stated what a dormitory (a set of rooms). I want to output a 2d array which states the room and which children are assigned to it but I'm having trouble with actual writing the constraints and how to actually write the code to assign children to their rooms.

-edit, I have no idea why the code wasn't there the first time but it's below.

```
enum CHILDREN; %variable name will be the child's name

array[CHILDREN] of string:gender; %input is M or F

array[CHILDREN] of int:age;

array[CHILDREN] of string:disability; %input is Y or N

enum ROOMS;

array[ROOMS] of string:access; %if accessible to those with a disability, input is Y or N

array[ROOMS] of int:size;

array[ROOMS] of CHILDREN: occupy; %rooms have children, trying to solve for this

array[ROOMS] of string:label; %gender label for room, idea is to distinguish rooms
var set of ROOMS:dorm; %defining what a dormitory is i.e. a set of rooms

constraint forall(r in ROOMS)(length(occupy) == (size-1)); %number of children in the room equal to its size-1

solve satisfy
```

This is some data from the dzn/data file.

```
ROOMS={1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
access=[Y,Y,Y,Y,N,N,N];
size=[5,6,5,6,4,7,4];
occupy=[];
label=['','','','','','',''];

CHILDREN={A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T};
gender=[M,M,F,F,F,F,M,M,M,M,M,M,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F];
age=[3,5,6,7,8,10,3,5,6,7,7,8,9,9,10,10,10,11,11,13];
disability=[Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N];
```

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into

Comment: Would you mind add the data as well (a small dataset)? It's much easier to help if the model is as complete as possible.

Comment: My usual approach is to use binary assignment variables `x[CHILDREN,ROOMS]`. I.e. `x[i,j] = 1 if child i is assigned to room j and 0 otherwise`. The rest of the model becomes easy when using these variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are just getting started with MiniZinc. So I'd like to welcome you to the community. You seem to be getting the hang of declaring data in the language, but you might want to have a look at the different data types. Gender for example is ideally not a string, but either a enum or, if you are using only two types, then you could use the Boolean type. Similarly disability and access can be changed to the boolean types.

The most important decision in a model is which variables to choose. In the model I've provided I chose to use set variables, where every room is represented by a set of the children that occupy it. You can set the gender labels for the room from the data file, but since the data was not given I've turned this into a variable as well, letting the solver decide which gender should be assigned to which room.

When adding constraints you should always try to use global constraints, so to enforce that all children are only in one room, we use `all_disjoint`. We can also use the `array_union` function to ensure that all children are assigned to a room. The other constraints should probably speak for themselves.

The final (soft) constraint can be seen as an objective of the model. We would like to minimize the age difference in the rooms. This means we first have to compute this difference and then set it as the objective function (`solve minimize`). Note that adding these computations and the objective do add a lot of complexity to the model.

To output the assignments we can use an output statement. You can likely get your output any way you like, but I prefer to display both the assignments made and the objective function that we are computing.

**Model**

```
include "globals.mzn";

enum CHILDREN; %variable name will be the child's name

enum GENDER = { M, F }; % NOTE: Enums are better fit for this purpose than strings

array[CHILDREN] of GENDER: gender; %input is M or F
array[CHILDREN] of int: age;
array[CHILDREN] of bool: disability; %input is true or false

enum ROOMS;

array[ROOMS] of bool: access; %if accessible to those with a disability, input is true or false
array[ROOMS] of int: size;

array[ROOMS] of var set of CHILDREN: occupy; %rooms have children, trying to solve for this
array[ROOMS] of var GENDER: label; %gender label for room, idea is to distinguish rooms

constraint all_disjoint(occupy); % Children can only be assigned one room
constraint array_union(occupy) == CHILDREN; % All children must be assigned a room
constraint forall(r in ROOMS)(card(occupy[r]) <= size[r]); %number of children in the room smaller or equal to its size
constraint forall(r in ROOMS)(forall(o in occupy[r]) (label[r] == gender[o])); % All children in the room must have the gender assigned to the room
constraint forall(r in ROOMS) (forall(o in occupy[r] where disability[o]) (access[r] = true)); % Children with a disability can only be placed in accessible rooms

array[ROOMS] of var int: age_difference;
constraint forall(r in ROOMS) ( age_difference[r] = sum(c1,c2 in occupy[r] where c1 < c2) (abs(age[c1] - age[c2])));

solve minimize sum(age_difference);

output ["ROOM \(r) (\(label[r])): \(occupy[r])\n  Age difference: \(age_difference[r])\n" | r in ROOMS] ++ ["Objective: \(sum(age_difference))\n"];
```

**Data**

```
ROOMS={r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7};
access=[true,true,true,true,false,false,false];
size=[5,6,5,6,4,7,4];

CHILDREN={cA,cB,cC,cD,cE,cF,cG,cH,cI,cJ,cK,cL,cM,cN,cO,cP,cQ,cR,cS,cT};
gender=[M,M,F,F,F,F,M,M,M,M,M,M,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F];
age=[3,5,6,7,8,10,3,5,6,7,7,8,9,9,10,10,10,11,11,13];
disability=[true,true,true,true,true,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false];
```

There is a lot that can be changed in this model: you can have a look and see if you can optimise the constraints used, change the output to be the way you like, choose a different objective functions (e.g., for fairness it is sometimes better to optimise the minimum instead of the sum), or even change the choice in variables and rewrite the constraints.

This version of the model was tested using the chuffed solver, and seems to perform reasonably well. Remember to set the `-a` flag, or "show all solutions" in the IDE, when running a optimisation problem.